# subview (like popout effect)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
settingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,-400, 400, 325)];

settingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:settingView];


CGRect frame = settingView.frame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:.500];

frame.origin.y = 0;

settingView.frame = frame;

**[self.view setAlpha:.30f];

[self.settingView setAlpha:1.0f];**

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I want the background to be blurred off, except settingView. But the whole view is being affected. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting alpha on the view, but if you only want the background to be transparent – I assume that is what you mean by 'blurred' – you need to set the background color to be transparent instead:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.3];
```